# Shared Hosting/VPS for mediawiki engine

Tags: hosting, mediawiki

I am looking for cheap but flexible shared hosting or VPS for installing mediawiki with possibility to set up multilanguage subdomains for wiki. Maybe someone knows hosting with easy way to set up multilanguage support for mediawiki?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A 256 Mb VPS should be enough according your needs. 128 wouldn't be okay as you need an InnoDB table space. Ideal seems to be 256 burstable to 512.

People have reported on MediaWiki support IRC channels or mailing lists to be happy with MediaWiki installations on VPS from Linode, RootBSD and Johncompanies providers.

None of them offers automated MediaWiki installation. That would be difficult to achieve automated language installations, as they could be very tricky and depend a lot of your requirements of links between these sites.